# Application User Authentication

Tags: authentication, architecture, credentials, application-design

I have a question about user authentication when developing an iOS application. When the user launches the application, they will be prompted with the home screen which will prompt them to input a valid username and password. Once their credentials are validated they will be able to access the rest of the application. I have no idea on how to create this validation operation. I know how to create the visual portion of the application, however, anything beyond that i don't understand. In short, how do you create an application that needs credentials from the user to function?

Comment: To add to this question, applications like Paypal, Mint.com, Facebook, Twitter, and The App Store use credentials to validate users. This can't be that complicated or a big secret to know how to do this. I just need some help in doing this for my application development. Im surprised apple hasn't made a tutorial for creating apps that user user credential validation. Then again, maybe they have and i just don't know about it :-)

Comment: This question really doesn't have to do with iOS, but with general application design

Comment: Since I will only be developing in iOS, my only concern is iOS.

Comment: Yes, but the question isn't iOS specific.

Comment: In my case it is. Im not looking to argue. I just wanted an answer to my question and you haven't provided one. All you have done is pointed out things that are obvious and known mainly to individuals who have done this before. I appreciate your response but it in no way answered my question.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a guide to creating a functional User Validation form within Xcode for iOS. Wether it uses an external server to validate the credentials, Core Data, or some variation, that would be great. Honestly, I would love to know how apple does this within their own applications. If anyone knows where I can find a guide like this or has any information I would greatly appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, Apple will reject your app if it cannot do *something* useful without authentication.
Second, you collect the inputs from the user, then you will have to fire off a NSURLConnection to your server in order to authenticate, observe the response and act accordingly.

Comment: I know that Apple will reject it if it can't do something useful. I understand that I collect the inputs from the user. "Fire off a NSURLConnection to your server in order to authenticate, observe the response and act accordingly." Is there any possible way that you can explain this a little further in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your server is set up, considering you are validating with your server. You'd use `NSURLConnection` in somewhat this manner, this is how I do it in my own app (tailored to your parameters):

```
+ (NSDictionary *)executeCallWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request {
  NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error]; 
  NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  error = nil;
  NSDictionary *result = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
  if (error == nil && response.statusCode == 200) {
    NSLog(@"%i", response.statusCode);
  } else {
    NSLog(@"%@", dataString);
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
  return result;
}

+ (NSDictionary *)executePostWithRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request {
  request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
  return [self executeCallWithRequest:request];
}

+ (NSDictionary *)loginUserWithCredentials:(NSDictionary *)userCredentials {
  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", YOUR_URL]];
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

  NSString *requestFields = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
  for (NSString *key in [userCredentials allKeys]) {
    requestFields = [requestFields stringByAppendingFormat:@"(param name)&", key, [userCredentials objectForKey:key]];
  }

  //removes the trailing &
  requestFields = [requestFields substringToIndex:requestFields.length - 1];
  requestFields = [requestFields stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  NSData *requestData = [requestFields dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  request.HTTPBody = requestData;

  return [self executePostWithRequest:request];
}
```

In my case I respond with a JSON encoded array.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What kind of server? How would you validate with a server? Ive never created an app with validation before so forgive my ignorance. Will I need additional frameworks activated within Xcode to use validation?

Comment: No, Charles you don't. And I mean that you should have a server side program running, or not? What are you validating against? Where do you save your user information?